# Parallel trend analysis in a two period panel data

Tags: difference-in-difference, trend, parallel-analysis

I have a dataset , which is in panel nature for two time periods. I would like to whether it is possible to perform a DID analysis, and if yes is it possible to do a parallel trend analysis for only two time periods.

Answer (score 0):

For a canonical DiD that includes only two-time periods, the assumption of parallel trends involves a counterfactual and cannot be observed, i.e. you're assuming that absent intervention trends would have continued in parallel but there's no way to test. What you can do is see (test) if the trends were parallel before the treatment, but you'd have to have data for two (not just one) pre-treatment time periods.

So with only data for two time periods, you can do a DiD, but you may have very little reason to believe that trends were parallel before treatment. That being said, if I remember correctly, the famous minimum wage study by Card and Krueger had only data for two time periods--though a follow-up study showed that trends were generally not parallel.

Comment: Thank you for the insight Sir. Does that mean there is no point in doing a DID analysis for a two time period data?

Comment: It depends. Is there some other way that you could convince us/yourself that pre-trends are likely parallel?

Comment: is it possible with a graphical analysis? only in the pre-treatment period?

Comment: You would have to have two data points in the pre-treatment period, otherwise you'd have points instead of lines. :)

Answer (score 0):

While not ideal, you can always test the parallel tends on another data set that has a similar set of outcomes, or even an aggregate version of the outcomes you are measuring.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).